# How to pass instance into class that implements BeforeAllCallback

Tags: java, junit5

I would like to know how can I pass a class instance into the BeforeAllCallback.

The test:

```
@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
public class IntegrationSpec extends DockerComposeAbstraction {

    Myobject example = new Myobject("something");

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        //Test something
    }
}
```

MyExtension class:

```
public class MyExtension implements BeforeAllCallback {

    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(instanceOfMyObject.getSomething);
    }
}
```

Can I do this with junit5 @ExtendWith annotation?

Answer (score 2):

First of all the `example` object should be a static field if you wish to use it in a `beforeAll` method.

Then you can use [programatic extension registration](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-programmatic) to save `example` as field in your extension:

```java
public class IntegrationSpec extends DockerComposeAbstraction {

    static Myobject example = new Myobject("something");

    @RegisterExtension
    static MyExtension myExtension = new MyExtension(example);

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        //Test something
    }
}
```

And the extension:

```java
public class MyExtension implements BeforeAllCallback {

    private Myobject example;

    public MyExtension(Myobject example) {
        this.example = example;
    }

    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(example.getSomething());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it can be done with `static` fields. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A `BeforeAllCallback` always has access to the `ExtensionContext` which provides an `Optional<Object> getTestInstance()` method.

For a `BeforeAllCallback`, that will return an *empty* `Optional` by default, since the default test instance lifecycle mode is `PER_METHOD`; however, you can change that default behavior by annotating your test class with `@TestInstance(PER_CLASS)`. If you switch to the per-class lifecycle mode, `getTestInstance()` will return an `Optional` containing the test instance.